# SSRS - trying to get total rows by using CountRows function

Tags: function, reporting-services

I am trying to get the total rows returned by each tablix. Each row returned is an error and I need to get the total errors. Each tablix has it own data set name so I am trying to use CountRows(data set) and add them together to get the total rows returned or total errors.

Code:
="Number of Errors: " & CountRows("Reader_Check")'' + '' & CountRows("Access_Panel_Check")''  + ''  & CountRows("Reader_Check")'' + '' &  CountRows("Alarm_Panel_Check")'' + '' &  CountRows("Alarm_Input_Check")'' + '' &  CountRows("Alarm_Output_Check")''  + '' & CountRows("Segment_Check")'' + '' &  CountRows("Access_Level_Check")'' + '' &  CountRows("Area_Check")''  + ''  & CountRows("Timezone_Check")'' + '' &  CountRows("Alarm_Check")

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are appending the `+` as a string?

I think you just need something like

```
="Number of Errors: " & 
(CountRows("Reader_Check") 
+ CountRows("Access_Panel_Check") 
+ CountRows("Reader_Check") 
+ CountRows("Alarm_Panel_Check") 
+ CountRows("Alarm_Input_Check") 
+ CountRows("Alarm_Output_Check") 
+ CountRows("Segment_Check") 
+ CountRows("Access_Level_Check") 
+ CountRows("Area_Check") 
+ CountRows("Timezone_Check") 
+ CountRows("Alarm_Check")
)
```

**Note: you have Reader_Check specified twice which I assume is incorrect**

Comment: Thanks Alan it works fine now. Yes Reader check should only be there once.